# flask returns 404 even though the url is matched

Tags: python, flask

I've been writing an auth API. The codes are available in [enter link description here](https://github.com/BigBorg/Auth) . The script I am running is authserver.py in the example directory. However, I always get an 404 response even though it seems to match the url_map. The printed result is:

```
<Config {'DEBUG': True, 'TESTING': False, 'PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS': None, 'PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION': None, 'SECRET_KEY': 'mykey', 'PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(31), 'USE_X_SENDFILE': False, 'LOGGER_NAME': '__main__', 'LOGGER_HANDLER_POLICY': 'always', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost.com', 'APPLICATION_ROOT': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_NAME': 'session', 'SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_PATH': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY': True, 'SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE': False, 'SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST': True, 'MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH': None, 'SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT': datetime.timedelta(0, 43200), 'TRAP_BAD_REQUEST_ERRORS': False, 'TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS': False, 'EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING': False, 'PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME': 'http', 'JSON_AS_ASCII': True, 'JSON_SORT_KEYS': True, 'JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR': True, 'JSONIFY_MIMETYPE': 'application/json', 'TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD': None, '__module__': 'Auth.config', 'MONGODB_HOST': 'localhost', 'MONGODB_DB': 'flaskAuth', 'MONGODB_PORT': '27017', 'MONGODB_USERNAME': None, 'MONGODB_PASSWORD': None, 'EMAIL_SALT': 'email', 'MAIL_SERVER': 'smtp.126.com', 'MAIL_USERNAME': 'youraccount', 'MAIL_PASSWORD': 'yourpassword', 'MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER': 'youraccount@126.com', '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Config' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Config' objects>, '__doc__': None}>
Map([<Rule '/auth/http/updatepassword' (OPTIONS, POST) -> Auth.http_update_password>,
 <Rule '/auth/http/updateemail' (OPTIONS, POST) -> Auth.http_update_email>,
 <Rule '/auth/http/sendemail' (OPTIONS, POST) -> Auth.http_send_email>,
 <Rule '/auth/http/register' (OPTIONS, POST) -> Auth.http_register>,
 <Rule '/auth/http/logout' (OPTIONS, POST) -> Auth.http_logout>,
 <Rule '/auth/http/login' (OPTIONS, POST) -> Auth.http_login>,
 <Rule '/' (OPTIONS, HEAD, GET) -> home>,
 <Rule '/auth/http/emailactivate/<email_token>/' (OPTIONS, HEAD, GET) -> Auth.http_email_activate>,
 <Rule '/static/<filename>' (OPTIONS, HEAD, GET) -> static>])
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 165-506-181
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Mar/2017 15:03:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Even though I only return a string in "/", it still returns 404.

Comment: Also, test client works perfectly, it has even passed all tests.

Comment: Oh, I've found out what went wrong. The "SERVER_NAME" setting should be in accordance with current address or flask will return 404 for every request. In development phase, it should be set as "locahost:port". I thought this setting is only used when we need to use url_for method. Seems flask uses it inside as well.